# GET parameters in htaccess url rewriting

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm doing some url rewrite with htaccess. I have this:

```
RewriteRule ^mesas$ http://www.myweb.net/piezas.php?pos=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^sillas$ http://www.myweb.net/piezas.php?pos=2 [L]
RewriteRule ^taburetes$ http://www.myweb.net/piezas.php?pos=3 [L]
```

This is working.  If I write the url http://www.myweb.net/mesas 
I get http://www.myweb.net/piezas.php?pos=1.

Now I want to add other parameters. Example:
I have this http://www.myweb.net/mesas?pag=10
and I want this: http://www.myweb.net/piezas.php?pos=1&pag=10

I'm try with:

```
RewriteRule ^mesas?(.*)$ http://www.myweb.net/piezas.php?pos=1&$1 [L]
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^mesas$?(.*) http://www.myweb.net/piezas.php?pos=1&$1 [L]
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding flag **QSA**, like this:

```
RewriteRule ^mesas$ http://www.myweb.net/piezas.php?pos=1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^sillas$ http://www.myweb.net/piezas.php?pos=2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^taburetes$ http://www.myweb.net/piezas.php?pos=3 [L,QSA]
```

It will *append* the incoming query string to the existing one.